# Django REST Serializers - passing a value when creating a new object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I'm having problems in passing an argument when creating an object with Django REST serializers.

models.py

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False)
    description = models.TextField()
...

class Hypothesis(models.Model):
    hypothesis = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False)
    project = models.ManyToManyField(Project)
    test_conducted = models.ManyToManyField('Interview', through='HypothesesFeedback') 
...
```

serializers.py

```py
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name','description','company_name']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class HypothesisSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Hypothesis
        fields = ['hypothesis','area','details', 'project']

    def get_alternate_name(self, obj):
        project = self.context["project_id"]
```

views.py

```py
class ProjectRestCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer

...

class HypothesisRestCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Hypothesis.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HypothesisSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context["project_id"] = 8 #self.kwargs['project_id']
        return context
...
```

I'm currently unable to default the project id when creating a new object for class hypothesis. In the example above, I'm hardcoding a value just for test purposes, but what I'd need to reach is that when I create a new hypothesis starting from a given project page, the project is automatically filled, rather than the user having to manually select it.

Using Django, rather than Django REST, I'd be able to achieve that using the code below:

```py
class HypothesisCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = Hypothesis
    form_class = HypothesisForm
    template_name = 'new_hypothesis.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save()
        project = form.data['project']
        p = Project.objects.filter(id=project)
        obj.project.set(p)

        return super(HypothesisCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HypothesisCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['p_id'] = self.kwargs['project']

        return context

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):

        return reverse('project_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['project']})
```

Any idea on how to reach the same with Django REST serializers?

**EDIT #1**

models.py

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False)
    description = models.TextField()
...

class Hypothesis(models.Model):
    hypothesis = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    test_conducted = models.ManyToManyField('Interview', through='HypothesesFeedback') 
...
```

using Django rather than Django REST, I achieve the defaulting of the project when creating a new hypothesis, using get_context_data:

```py
VIEW:

class HypothesisCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = Hypothesis
    form_class = HypothesisForm
    template_name = 'new_hypothesis.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save()
        project = form.data['project']
        p = Project.objects.filter(id=project)
        obj.project.set(p)

        return super(HypothesisCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HypothesisCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['p_id'] = self.kwargs['project']

        return context

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):

        return reverse('project_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['project']})

FORM:

class HypothesisForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Hypothesis
        fields = ['hypothesis','area','details']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        super(HypothesisForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["project"] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

I tried doing the same with the serializer, but without success.

```py
VIEW:

class HypothesisRestCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Hypothesis.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HypothesisSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context["project_id"] = 8 #self.kwargs['project_id']
        return context



SERIALIZER:

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name','description','company_name']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class HypothesisSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Hypothesis
        fields = ['hypothesis','area','details', 'project'] #

    def get_alternate_name(self, obj):
        project = self.context["project_id"]
```

any idea what should I do differently?

Comment: why `ManyToManyField` ? each hypothesis can have may projects but dose any project work on many hypothesises ?

Comment: for each project, there are many hypotheses to be tested. Actually, the intention is that each hypothesis is linked to only one project

Comment: then use `Foraignkey` instead.

Comment: you're right, thanks for the hint! Would you know also how to pass the project id as parameter in the serializer, so that when I create a new hypothesis from project N, the value N is automatically assigned by the system, rather than the user having to select it manually?

Comment: ask that specific question in detail with modified code and specifying your exact problem. put its link in here.

Comment: thanks, I've edited the question above

Comment: it looks like you are sending `project_id` with url for `HypothesisRestCreate` instead of json data. it it correct ?

Comment: correct - in the scenario with Django rather than Django REST, I'm doing that. With Django REST, I thought I could use the same approach, but I'm happy to consider alternatives (unfortunately I'm new to Django REST framework)

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `HypothesisRestCreate` as following

```py
class HypothesisRestCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Hypothesis.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HypothesisSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['project'] = self.kwargs['project_id']
        return super(HypothesisRestCreate, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # def get_serializer_context(self): -- dont need for this purpose
```

and `HypothesisSerializer` as following

```py
class HypothesisSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Hypothesis
        fields = ['hypothesis','area','details', 'project']

    # def get_alternate_name(self, obj):  --dont need for this purpose
```